# React JS , problem with compiling the first component with JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am starting to learn react Js following the guide of a book named React Quickly by Azat Mardan,

i m in the step of using JSX in my code using vscode,

my code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<script src="js/react.js"></script>
<script src="js/react-dom.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="content"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
let helloWorldReactElement = <h1>Hello world! </h1>
class HelloWorld extends React.component {
  reder() {
    return <div>
      {helloWorldReactElement}
      {helloWorldReactElement}
      </div>
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <HelloWorld />,
  document.getElementById('content')
)
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

but in the browser i have an error in the console that says : index.html:10 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in this line

```
let helloWorldReactElement = <h1>Hello world! </h1>
```

if someone knows how i can fix that i am grateful

thank you

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">` is not correct because you're using JSX not JavaScript. JSX needs to be transpiled into JS first.

Comment: ReactJS, unlike JS or HTML, is 100% cross-browser compatible.  That's one of its best advantages; it can only do that by being compiled, look into `npm`, `npm install`, and `npm build`.

Comment: @yousaf i changed it but now the error is in line 13
 
return <div>

index.html:13 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you are using the JSX syntactic sugar to build your UI component and browsers don't understand it,you'll have to transpile it to JS first before it can work.

You can use Babel to your page, and add `type=text/babel` to your script tag. [Read More](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2016/12/babel-for-javascript/)

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
 //your code
</script>
```